# Not Adding Contents to New Line while writing to a file in Append Mode

Tags: php

```
     <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file="get.php";
    $open = fopen($file, "a+"); //open the file, (get.php).

    fwrite($open, "Name: " .$_POST['user'] . "/n"); //print / write the name.
    fwrite($open, "Colour: ". $_POST['color'] . "/n"); //print / write the colour.
    fclose($open); //close the opened file 

    echo "Log File Entry Had Been Made"; 
    }
     ?>
```

But The Output is written to get.php as -> /nName: The Name Posted/nColour: Colour Posted/n
 Please help if you have time, Thanks All.

Comment: Shouldn't you use \n instead of /n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character is "\n", not "/n". Just replace that, it'll work.